# Resize & Crop Category Images

Tags: image, category

I'd like to resize category images in my website, into square thumbnails. I have found and placed the following function in Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php:

```
public function getResizedImage($width, $height = null, $quality = 100) {
    if (! $this->getImage ())
        return false;

    $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir ( 'media' ) . DS . "catalog" . DS . "category" . DS . $this->getImage ();
    if (! is_file ( $imageUrl ))
        return false;

    $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir ( 'media' ) . DS . "catalog" . DS . "product" . DS . "cache" . DS . "cat_resized" . DS . $this->getImage ();// Because clean Image cache function works in this folder only
    if (! file_exists ( $imageResized ) && file_exists ( $imageUrl ) || file_exists($imageUrl) && filemtime($imageUrl) > filemtime($imageResized)) :
        $imageObj = new Varien_Image ( $imageUrl );
        $imageObj->constrainOnly ( true );
        $imageObj->keepAspectRatio ( true );
        $imageObj->keepFrame ( false );
        $imageObj->quality ( $quality );
        $imageObj->resize ( $width, $height );
        $imageObj->save ( $imageResized );
    endif;

    if(file_exists($imageResized)){
        return Mage::getBaseUrl ( 'media' ) ."/catalog/product/cache/cat_resized/" . $this->getImage ();
    }else{
        return $this->getImageUrl();
    }

}
```

and this is how it's used in template files:

```
<img src="<?php echo $category->getResizedImage(100,100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>" />
```

But it's not working propely, images are not cropped and they're not resized into 100x100 pixels.

This function is suggested by many people having the same issue, but it's just not working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: try this - https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-resize-category-images (self)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your code here,

```
$imageObj = new Varien_Image ( $imageUrl );
$imageObj=$imageObj->constrainOnly ( true )
->keepAspectRatio ( true )
->keepFrame ( false )
->quality ( $quality )
->resize ( $width, $height )
->save ( $imageResized );
```

This code will work.because you are not storing the return values of each code you used after this `$imageObj = new Varien_Image ( $imageUrl )`.

Comment: thank you for your answer but your code gives an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$imageObj'..."

Comment: @ktsixit now try with edited code;and dont just copy paste it Please type it.

Comment: The error is fixed now but the images are not being cropped. f.e if an image's original dimensions is 148x205, getResizedImage(100,100) gives a thumb with dimensions: 72x100. I'd like to get cropped square images.

Comment: `keepframe(true)` will help you